# How do I convert Range[ ] to integer/class value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make an App Script code where every time there is a match for the term CM, a new row is made underneath. The problem is, the "FindAll" method returns all the ranges where CM exists and the "getRow" method isn't able to convert all of these ranges into integer values for the "insertRowsAfter" method.

```
function searchString() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Team Ideas');
  var search = "CM"
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search).findAll();
  var row = textFinder.getRow();

  sheet.insertRowsAfter(row, 1);
  sheet.getActiveRange().offset(sheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, sheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you loop through the matches one at a time using `findNext()`, then `getRow` will return a more sensible value.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it.

Comment: TextFinder returns a range `Range.getSheet()` gets the sheet and `Range.getRow()` gets the row and `Range.getColumn()` gets the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I have done with the textFinder findAll()

```
function regexSearch(sObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sObj.ssid);
  var tf=ss.createTextFinder(sObj.pattern).useRegularExpression(true);
  var all=tf.findAll();
  var matches='';
  for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
    matches+=Utilities.formatString('Sheet: %s Cell: %s Row: %s Col: %s Value: %s\n',all[i].getSheet().getName(),all[i].getA1Notation(),all[i].getRow(),all[i].getColumn(),all[i].getValue());
  }
  if(matches) {
    sObj.matches=matches;
  }else{
    sObj.message(Utilities.formatString('No Matches found for %s',sObj.pattern));
  }
  return sObj;
}
```

You will notice that the method findAll() returns a range from which you can determine sheet, row and column.

Answer (score 1):

#### Requirement:

Find all occurrences of "CM" in a sheet and and insert a new row below each occurrence.

---

#### Solution:

Loop through the array already created by `var textFinder` and create a row for each object.

---

#### Example:

```
function searchString() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Team Ideas');
  var search = "CM"
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search).findAll();
  for (i = 0; i < textFinder.length; i++) {
    var row = textFinder[i].getRow();
    sheet.insertRowAfter(row + i);
  }
}
```

---

#### Explanation:

Your `var textFinder` is already creating an array that looks like this:

```
[Range, Range, Range, Range]
```

So all we're doing in the new `for` loop is looping through each item in this array (the range for each occurrence of "CM") and inserting a row after that range using `insertRowAfter()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Really helped me understand!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to treat textFinder as an array of objects and not an object. You can see from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findAll()) that findAll() returns an array.

The following will go through each item and insert a blank row. Note that the array is reversed before doing so. This is done to preserve the index of where the rows are. If we went down the list then we would have to account for the change in the index in later matches.

Try this:

```
function searchString() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Team Ideas');
  var search = "CM"
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search).findAll();
  textFinder.reverse();
  textFinder.forEach(function(t){
    var row = t.getRow();
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(row, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.